# Discord.py How to embed multiple buttons in one package

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I rewrite this code embedding all buttons in one function? The current implementation violates DRY, and I'd like to reduce the repetition.

```
@discord.ui.button(label="Sistemas", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, emoji="")
async def button1 (self, Interaction:discord.Interaction,Button:discord.ui.button, rol="Sistemas"):
    await self.give_role(Interaction, rol)

@discord.ui.button(label="Quimica", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="")
async def button2 (self, Interaction:discord.Interaction,Button:discord.ui.button, rol="Quimica"):
    await self.give_role(Interaction, rol)

@discord.ui.button(label="Electrica", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji="⚡")
async def button3 (self, Interaction:discord.Interaction,Button:discord.ui.button, rol="Electrica"):
    await self.give_role(Interaction, rol)

@discord.ui.button(label="Mecanica", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, emoji="⚙️")
async def button4 (self, Interaction:discord.Interaction,Button:discord.ui.button, rol="Mecanica"):
    await self.give_role(Interaction, rol)
```

I expected to get something like one function and replacing the values in parameters for every button, having less code lines.